# Is it imbalanced give the Eldritch Knight's Bard spells instead of Wizard?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, class-feature, homebrew, balance

I am building a Fighter character in D&D 5e, starting at level six. None of the archetypes as written really fit my idea, but the Eldritch Knight is closest-- except for the Wizard spells.

What would be the balance implications of swapping out the EK's spell list in favor the Bard spell list?

The biggest concern is likely the fact that the Bard list has access to spells such as Cure Wounds and Healing Word; what would happen if these options were removed? Left in?

Comment: So are you look at full-on swapping the lists? Or just some substitutions? I'm confused by your "what would happen if *these options* were removed" bit.

Comment: Fully replacing the Wizard list with the Bard list. The last paragraph is meant to convey "I'm aware that the healing spells are the most likely problem, so so answers both with and without them would be appreciated."

Comment: I've voted to close as opinion based. This is purely subjective, and invites a lot of "but what if" scenarios. Also, the Eldritch Knight doesn't get to draw from the full Wizard list (except in a very limited fashion). It only really gets to draw from the Abjuration and Evocation schools on the Wizard list, which is actually far more restricted.

Answer (score 2):

The best way to swap up spell lists without unbalancing too much is simply to flavorize your spells. Simply changing the descriptions and appearance of your spells may be enough to achieve what you desire. This is assuming you don't want access to specific spells but rather an improved mouth-feel for your class. The way you've worded the question makes it seem like you're seeking the latter.